# how to draw a square in to a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a problem with my C# Windows-Forms project. I am trying to draw a square and I want to display the square inside a picture-box. How can I do that?

This is my function for drawing the square:

```
public void DrawingSquares(int x, int y)//the function gets x and y to know where to print the square.
    {
        Graphics graphicsObj;
        graphicsObj = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 100);
        graphicsObj.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: my vs solution]

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.pictureBox1.Image = this.Draw(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height);
    }

    public Bitmap Draw(int width, int height)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Tomato), 10, 10, 100, 100);

        return bitmap;
    }
  }
}
```

this is my Form1.cs

you should have something simillar

Comment: when im replace my fuction to your function its stiil gives me alot of eror im sorry:(

Comment: Error 1 The name 'PixelFormat' does not exist in the current context c:\users\08_11_2010\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs 25 52 WindowsFormsApplication3

Comment: Error 2 The name 'SmoothingMode' does not exist in the current context c:\users\08_11_2010\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs 27 38 WindowsFormsApplication3

Comment: add this using directives to the top of your file:
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

Answer (score 1):

You must add a `PaintEventHandler` inside your picture box and draw the rectangle inside it:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Bitmap Draw()
{
   var bitmap = new Bitmap(width,height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
   var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
   graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Tomato), 10, 10, 100, 100);
}

this.pictureBox1.Image = new PieChart().Draw();
```

so if you just return a bitmap, it works

Comment: the public Bitmap Draw replaces your square function, you can rename the one i wrote if you wish. the this.pictureBox1.Image = new PieChart().Draw(); belongs in the part were you want do assign your picture to the imagebox

Comment: tnx :) when im adding your functin

Comment: when im add this row this.pictureBox1.Image = new PieChart().Draw(); it gives me alot of error like Error 1 Invalid token 'this' in class, struct, or interface member declaration F:\drawsquare1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 26 9 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: yeah sorry, see my second answer